# Price of a Google Conversational Action after releasing it

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

Are there any costs - and if so, which – for **releasing** a conversational action I've built?

It is obvious that Firebase and/or Dialogflow cost some money, but what if you actually *don’t use any* of these services? I only use Google Assistant to capture voice input, then I call a webhook (I host the server) and reply with a message, which GA reads aloud.  Would I get the STT and TTS without charge in this scenario (I doubt so)?

Note: A similar question has already been asked here

- [Cost of developing a Google Assistant App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630105/cost-of-developing-a-google-assistant-app)

However the answers for this question only cover costs during the development stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not charge for use of the Actions Console, Actions Builder (but see below), or Actions SDK.

So assuming you're doing speech-to-text and text-to-speech strictly for running an Action - there will be no additional charge.

As you note, there may be charges for other Google services if you use them. This may include the built-in code editor with the Actions Builder (which uses Firebase behind the scenes)